# Branch init between slash and main activity

Tags: android, branch.io

My app launches a `SplashActivity` followed by a `MainActivity`. I run `branch.initSession` in the `SplashActivity` but it's taking about 1.5 seconds to return to the listener which delays the launch of the `MainActivity`. I would like to reduce this time.

My ideas are:

1. run `branch.initSession` in the `MainActivity` instead.
2. run `branch.initSession` in `SplashActivity`, launch `MainActivity`, then pass the branch to the `MainActivity` using an eventbus for processing.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to solve this issue?

Cheers, Duane.

Answer (score 2):

Amruta from [Branch](http://branch.io) here.

By default, Branch will delay the install call only for up to 1.5 seconds. We delay the install call in order to capture the install referrer string passed through Google Play, which increases attribution and deferred deep linking accuracy. We do not delay any other call, and the install call only occurs the first time a user opens your app.

If we receive the referrer string before 1.5 seconds, we will immediately fire the call, meaning this delay is up to 1.5 seconds, but not guaranteed to take that long.

If you’d like to optimize the first install call, simply paste the following code in your Application class, and we will not delay the first install call.

```
public final class CustomApplicationClass {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      // initialize the Branch object
      Branch.setPlayStoreReferrerCheckTimeout(0);
      Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not during the first install. This is anytime I open the app well after the install. My `SplashActivity` will complete its tasks and start opening the `MainActivity` before the branch listener has returned.

Comment: @duane Are you changing the content/view in your Main Activity based on the link parameters? If not, you can always initialize Branch in your Main Activity. There will be some network delay for the callback to complete. You can avoid this lag in your Splash Activity by initializing Branch in the Main Activity. Make sure to update your Manifest appropriately to define the intents in the Main Activity.

Comment: I did some testing where I would install, test the time for first launch, quit and reopen the app for a second launch.

Comment: I did some testing where I would install, test the time for first launch and relaunch the app (time shown in brackets). With no branch: ~450ms (~330ms). With branch.getAutoInstance: ~480 (~350ms). With branch.initSession: 1500-2000ms (1500-200ms). With checkout time = 0: 1500-2000ms (1500-2000ms). So the the branch listener adds a significant ~1500ms delay to my app. That increases the launch time by 3x, which is noticeable. Edit: I accidentally submitted too early.

Comment: On first install launch, the Splash Activity will initialize the app based on the link parameters. In subsequent app launches, the app can process the link in either the Splash Activity or Main Activity. It's good to know this delay is form the network because I can't let my Splash Activity wait too long for teh entwork. I think I've found a solution. I'll post this and wouldn't mind your thoughts on the solution. Cheers

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. If first launch, wait for the parameters in the Splash Activity
2. If not first launch, pass the Branch parameters on to the Application which would pass the parameters onto any listener to process. If there is no listener, then it can try to process it in the Splash Activity or save it for later.

I'm not sure if this is good practice, but I thought it'll be simpler than adding a Event Bus library. Would be happy to hear some feedback.

The Application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private Listener branchListener = null;

    public interface Listener {
        void onBranchLinkReceived(JSONObject params, BranchError error);
    }

    public void registerBranchListener(Listener listener) {
        branchListener = listener;
    }

    public void unregisterBranchListener() {
         branchListener = null;
    }

    public boolean branchLinkReceived(JSONObject params, BranchError error) {
        if (branchListener != null) {
            branchListener.onBranchLinkReceived(params, error);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

In the Splash Activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject params, BranchError error) {

                if (error == null) {
                   if (firstLaunch) {
                       processParamsInSplashActivity(params);
                   } else {
                       boolean isProcessed = ((MyApp) getApplication()).branchLinkReceived(params, error);
                   }
                }
           }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyApp.Listener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MyApp) getApplication()).registerBranchListener(this);
        ...
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ((MyApp) getApplication()).unregisterBranchListener();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBranchLinkReceived(JSONObject params, BranchError error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Branch link received: " + params);
    }
}
```